Excel Discrete column-wise selection from area
I'd like to be able to select an area column-wise (as individual columns). Manually holding down CTRL works fine for a few columns but when you've got 200 to select it becomes tedious. I'd like to be able to drag an area and then convert it from one solid area to the column-wise selection, i.e., turn multi column selection (left) into discrete column-wise selection (right).


Select the area then use CTRL to deselect those columns you do not want? Alternatively, hide the columns you don't want

Why do you need to select 200 indivjdual columns?

^^^ indeed, it does make this question look like an XY problem
